# Fill an object with text using keycodes (with the possibility for keyboard shortcuts)

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, keyevent, rebuild

Are there other ways to write text *with keycodes* apart from these two methods? However, the bad part by the following methods is that they cannot handle shortcuts like `shift + a`...

**1. Method**

Use a json-object filled with keycodes and characters, rebuild then the text while iterating over them and compare with typed keycodes.

example *(only for demonstration purposes)*:

```
var chars = {
  65: 'a',
  66: 'b',
  67: 'c',
  68: 'd',
  69: 'e'
  etc..
},
keys = {};

...push some keycodes to `keys`-array...
e.g: keys[(+new Date())] = 65;
     keys[(+new Date())] = 66;
     keys[(+new Date())] = 67;

...fill the output-string
var mark = null,
    timeout = 0,
    str = "";

    for(var t in keys) {
        if(mark) {
            timeout = tS - mark;
        } else {
            timeout = 0;
            mark = tS;
        }

        setTimeout(function(){
            str += keys[t];
        }, timeout);
    }

...return the string:
elem.text(str);
```

**2. Method**

Create an empty/shadow `input` and fill the values from it into a string (I'll not explain this method further, you can read here about it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8072440/1250044

**3. Method**

Not a real way but it should be noted:

```
var str = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
```

### A good way

I think the best way to do it it will be to trigger the `keyevent` like so:

```
$(document).trigger({type: 'keydown', which: x});
```

The disadvantage is, that this will not trigger a real `keydown`, so writing this way is not possible.

Comment: Those are pretty much the best ways out there. I'd suggest going for method #2, since it's the most reliable with capital letters etc.

Comment: @Cerbrus ...me too, however the problem is that it does not result in good performance when the textarea's value gets bigger.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "bad performance"? What's happening?

Comment: @Cerbus *it takes much storage because when the textarea's value gets bigger, it gets duplicated more and more until it becomes a huge 200MB file after a while of typing...*