# Record User Typing Exactly with time Difference in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to record user typing with an exact time difference letter by letter to replay it. I would like to do this in React with `setTimeout` function while replaying text is not one by one but this is an expected behaviour but I want one by one like a Queue System

Please don't suggest any plugins

Still not clear?

[image]

Code

```
import React,{Component} from 'react'

class Recorder extends Component{

    state = {
        text:"",
        viewText:[],
        typeInterval:0,
        typingText:[],
        oldTimestamp:0,

        textInput:"",
        delayedTime:0,

        replay:[]
    };

    globalTime = 0

    handleTextArea = e => {

        this.setState({
            textInput:e.target.value
        });
    };
    recordUserTyping = e => {
        this.setState({
            oldTimestamp:e.timeStamp
        });
        let timeDiff = e.timeStamp - this.state.oldTimestamp;
        let key = e.key
        let payload = {
            key,
            timeDiff
        };
        this.setState({
            typingText:[...this.state.typingText,payload],
        });

    };
    _startReplay = (i,data) => {

        let currentTimeDiff = data.timeDiff;

        return setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({
                replay:[...this.state.replay,data.key]
            })
        },currentTimeDiff)

    };
    startReplay = e => {

        return this.state.typingText.map((data,i) => {
            return this._startReplay(i,data)
        })

    };
    playRecorded = () => {
      return this.state.replay.map(data => {
          return data
      })
    };
    render(){
        console.log(this.state.replay,"STate Changhe");
        return(
            <div>
                <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" defaultValue={this.state.textInput} onKeyDown={this.recordUserTyping} onChange={this.handleTextArea} />
                <button onClick={this.startReplay}>Start</button>
                <p>{this.playRecorded()}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Recorder;
```

Hope I will get some help?

Comment: Do you have problem recording or replaying ? For recording you can check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8071415/how-to-efficiently-record-user-typing-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `startReplay` you are executing a bunch of `setTimeout` calls all at once, whose delays are the various `currentTimeDiff`.

Now, `currentTimeDiff` is defined as `e.timeStamp - this.state.oldTimestamp` which is the time difference relative to the PREVIOUS keydown.

This means that you are actually replaying the "quickest" keydowns first.
To fix this, wait for the previous `setTimeout` to finish before executing the next one in the queue.

Finally, set `0` as the waiting time for the first keydown.

```
recordUserTyping = e => {
  this.setState({
    oldTimestamp: e.timeStamp
  });
  // NOTE HOW timeDiff === 0 FOR THE FIRST EVENT
  let timeDiff = this.state.oldTimestamp
   ? e.timeStamp - this.state.oldTimestamp
   : 0;
  let key = e.key
  let payload = {
    key,
    timeDiff
  };
  this.setState({
    typingText: [...this.state.typingText, payload],
  });

};

_startReplay = (i,data) => {

    let currentTimeDiff = data.timeDiff;

    return setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
            replay:[...this.state.replay,data.key]
        });
        if (i+1 < this.state.typingText.length) {
          this._startReplay(i+1, this.state.typingText[i+1]);
        }
    },currentTimeDiff)

};

startReplay = e => {
    if (this.state.typingText.length === 0) return;
    return this._startReplay(0,this.state.typingText[0]);
};
```

See https://codesandbox.io/s/m752zrx9px for a fully working example